# Python - How to know whether an item is refering to a specifing element of a list

Tags: python, list

I've got two lists `A = [1,1,1]` and `B = [1]` which both contain the element 1.

If stumble uppon any `1`, is there a way of knowing if that `1` is refering to the 0th element in `B`, for example:

```
a = A[0]
b = B[0] # <-- This is refering to B at index 0

print(a is B[0], id(a) == id(B[0])) # this should return false
print(b is B[0], id(b) == id(B[0])) # this should return true
print(1 is B[0]) # this should also return false
```

Both `a` and `b` have the value of `1` and the output of the above is

```
True,True
True,True
```

What I want, is to know specifically if something is refering to an element of a list, in other words a function that instead only returns True for the second case in the above example.

Comment: What you have would work, `b is B[0]` However, `a is b`, because those are the same object, this is an implementation detail of CPython (small ints are cached)

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem, what are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: `a` has a value of 1 but is not the 0th element of `B`, instead `a` is the 0th element `A`. I'm trying to get the part `a = A[0]` to return that it is the 0th element of A and the part `b = B[0] ` that it is the 0th element of B

Comment: You are wrong. `a` **is** the zeroeth element of **both** `A` and `B`. That is what `is` is telling you. As I explained, there is **only a single `int` object with the value 1** in any given CPython process. But again, why do you care? What is it you are actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it will always be `True` as the variable is pointing to the same object.
If you have to differentiate between two 'equal' integers, what you can do, is do implement a wrapper class for it. By default, the identity of the class instances will be different and a comparison will fail.

Example:

````
class CustomInt:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.number
    
    
a = CustomInt(1)
b = CustomInt(1)
print(a==b)
--> False
```
````

Comment: well, the hash is irrelevant here, it's the `__eq__` that matters

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true, but if not overloaded, the ```__eq__``` uses the ```__hash__ ```property for comparison

Comment: I don't know why you think `__hash__` is used. It probably just compares by identity, using `is` (the equivalent internal CPython function, which is just a pointer equality). In any case, I think this may be a solution, but I suspect the OP could just circumvent the need to do this entirely.

Comment: Yeah was the first-guess solution in my head, too. But as @juanpa.arrivillaga said, probably this is an XY-problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just looked it up and you are right. Historical notice, until python 3.2 default hash was ```hash(x)==id(x)/16``` therefore it wouldnt have mattered. Nevertheless I corrected

Comment: @FloLie yeah, I [found it too](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23c5f93b83f78f295313e137011edb18b24c37c2/Objects/object.c#L685)  It does `res = (v == w) ? Py_True : Py_False;` where `v` and `w` are PyObject pointers, so it just hard-codes it!

Comment: Actually just using a wrapper class without any method works. If the class is named `I` then `A= [I(1),I(1),I(1)]` and `B = [I(1)]`. The example I have above will return true only in the 2nd case where in fact `b=B[0]` is the 0th element of b.

Comment: Just be carefull, that basic integer operations are not possible as such. You may need to implement arethmetic functions for the wrapper if you require them

Comment: or just by accessing `self.number` if the result is pointless.